# How was the CES production function derived?

Tags: mathematical-economics, production-function

The [Constant Elasticity of Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution) production function is defined as:

(*Taken from Wikipedia*)

$$Q=F \boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(a\boldsymbol{\cdot}K^r+(1-a)\boldsymbol{\cdot}L^r \right)^{1\over{r}}$$

Where:

$Q=$ the quantity of output

$F=$ [factor productivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_factor_productivity)

$a=$ Share parameter (i.e. $0 < a <1$)

$K, L=$ Quantities of production factors

$r= {\left(s-1 \right)\over{s}}$

$s= {1\over{1-r}}=$ Elasticity of subsitution

## My question:

Though this is a quite elegant formula, how is it derived?

Comment: I am perplexed by your question. What do you mean by "how is it derived"?

Comment: @denesp: Perhaps the OP wanted to ask who first proposed this functional form?

Comment: @HerrK.  Let us hope for clarification,  as that is a very different question.

Comment: His question makes sense - he is asking for the derivation of the functional form from its defining condition (i.e., constant elasticity of substitution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CES function can be derived directly from the condition of constant elasticity of substitution.  There are various ways to do this, but the simplest derivation occurs for a homothetic production function.  Suppose we start with a homothetic production function $Q = f^*(K, L)$ and we rewrite this in intensive form as:

$$\begin{matrix} q = f(k) & & q \equiv Q/L & & k \equiv K/L. \end{matrix}$$

For this case the elasticity of substitution $s$ can be shown to be:

$$s = - \frac{f'(k)(f(k) - kf'(k))}{kf(k)f''(k)}.$$

Letting $r \equiv (s-1)/s$ and re-arranging this equation gives the second-order differential equation:

$$\frac{kf(k)f''(k)}{1-r} + f'(k)(f(k) - kf'(k)) = 0.$$

This equation has general solution $q = f(k) =  c_0 (1 + c_1 k^r)^{1/r}$ where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are constants.  Parameterising with $a \equiv c_1$ and $F \equiv c_0 \cdot c_1^{1/r}$ and substituting to obtain the extensive form gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
Q = Lq = Lf(K/L) &= c_0 L \left( \left( 1 + c_1 \frac{K}{L} \right)^r \right)^{1/r} \\
&= c_0 \left(c_1 K^r + L^r \right)^{1/r} \\
&= F \left(a K^r + (1-a) L^r \right)^{1/r}.  
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The parameter $a$ can be interpreted as the capital intensity in production and the parameter $F$ can be interpreted as the overall efficiency of production.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you derived the elasticity? Its a shame ODE's aren't a requirement for Statisitcs and Economics students because it seems quite essential as demonstrated in the answer to fully understand